# How to make responsive block with MS fabric UI in SPFx?

Tags: javascript, css, sharepoint, spfx

We are using MS fabric UI for displaying contents in blocks. MS fabric UI uses 12 column layout and we are following exactly same. But problem is when parent div width is changing, blocks placement is not being adjusted. Below are layouts. To fix this do I need to write any custom JS, CSS or fabric UI is having any utility classes to achieve this?

Below is one interface when there are two columns in one row

[image]

Below is one interface when there are one column in one row
[image]

Comment: Can you share some sample code with us? It can help us to have a better understanding on what you have done.

Answer (score 1):

One time I had a similar problem and I used a tip from a an article I found about this. The sections in SharePoint Modern pages base on CanvasSection classes: CanvasSection-xl12, CanvasSection-xl6, CanvasSection-xl4, CanvasSection-xl8.

So we could add a custom .scss file (it's important that it won't be an .module.scss so the class names won't be changed with unique hash) with this kind of styles:

```
@import '~@microsoft/sp-office-ui-fabric-core/dist/sass/SPFabricCore.scss';

.CanvasSection.CanvasSection-col {
    &.CanvasSection-xl12 {
        .OneColumnSection-1 {
            @include ms-Grid-col;
            @include ms-xl1;
        }

        .OneColumnSection-2 {
            @include ms-Grid-col;
            @include ms-xl2;
        }

        .OneColumnSection-3 {
            @include ms-Grid-col;
            @include ms-xl3;
        }

        .OneColumnSection-4 {
            @include ms-Grid-col;
            @include ms-xl4;
        }

        .OneColumnSection-5 {
            @include ms-Grid-col;
            @include ms-xl5;
        }

        .OneColumnSection-6 {
            @include ms-Grid-col;
            @include ms-xl6;
        }

        .OneColumnSection-7 {
            @include ms-Grid-col;
            @include ms-xl7;
        }

        .OneColumnSection-8 {
            @include ms-Grid-col;
            @include ms-xl8;
        }

        .OneColumnSection-9 {
            @include ms-Grid-col;
            @include ms-xl9;
        }

        .OneColumnSection-10 {
            @include ms-Grid-col;
            @include ms-xl10;
        }

        .OneColumnSection-11 {
            @include ms-Grid-col;
            @include ms-xl11;
        }

        .OneColumnSection-12 {
            @include ms-Grid-col;
            @include ms-xl12;
        }
    }

    &.CanvasSection-xl6 {
        .TwoColumnsSection-1 {
            @include ms-Grid-col;
            @include ms-xl1;
        }

        .TwoColumnsSection-2 {
            @include ms-Grid-col;
            @include ms-xl2;
        }

        .TwoColumnsSection-3 {
            @include ms-Grid-col;
            @include ms-xl3;
        }

        .TwoColumnsSection-4 {
            @include ms-Grid-col;
            @include ms-xl4;
        }

        .TwoColumnsSection-5 {
            @include ms-Grid-col;
            @include ms-xl5;
        }

        .TwoColumnsSection-6 {
            @include ms-Grid-col;
            @include ms-xl6;
        }

        .TwoColumnsSection-7 {
            @include ms-Grid-col;
            @include ms-xl7;
        }

        .TwoColumnsSection-8 {
            @include ms-Grid-col;
            @include ms-xl8;
        }

        .TwoColumnsSection-9 {
            @include ms-Grid-col;
            @include ms-xl9;
        }

        .TwoColumnsSection-10 {
            @include ms-Grid-col;
            @include ms-xl10;
        }

        .TwoColumnsSection-11 {
            @include ms-Grid-col;
            @include ms-xl11;
        }

        .TwoColumnsSection-12 {
            @include ms-Grid-col;
            @include ms-xl12;
        }
    }

    &.CanvasSection-xl4 {
        .OneThird-1, .ThreeColumnsSection-1 {
            @include ms-Grid-col;
            @include ms-xl1;
        }

        .OneThird-2, .ThreeColumnsSection-2 {
            @include ms-Grid-col;
            @include ms-xl2;
        }

        .OneThird-3, .ThreeColumnsSection-3 {
            @include ms-Grid-col;
            @include ms-xl3;
        }

        .OneThird-4, .ThreeColumnsSection-4 {
            @include ms-Grid-col;
            @include ms-xl4;
        }

        .OneThird-5, .ThreeColumnsSection-5 {
            @include ms-Grid-col;
            @include ms-xl5;
        }

        .OneThird-6, .ThreeColumnsSection-6 {
            @include ms-Grid-col;
            @include ms-xl6;
        }

        .OneThird-7, .ThreeColumnsSection-7 {
            @include ms-Grid-col;
            @include ms-xl7;
        }

        .OneThird-8, .ThreeColumnsSection-8 {
            @include ms-Grid-col;
            @include ms-xl8;
        }

        .OneThird-9, .ThreeColumnsSection-9 {
            @include ms-Grid-col;
            @include ms-xl9;
        }

        .OneThird-10, .ThreeColumnsSection-10 {
            @include ms-Grid-col;
            @include ms-xl10;
        }

        .OneThird-11, .ThreeColumnsSection-11 {
            @include ms-Grid-col;
            @include ms-xl11;
        }

        .OneThird-12, .ThreeColumnsSection-12 {
            @include ms-Grid-col;
            @include ms-xl12;
        }
    }

    &.CanvasSection-xl8 {
        .TwoThirds-1 {
            @include ms-Grid-col;
            @include ms-xl1;
        }

        .TwoThirds-2 {
            @include ms-Grid-col;
            @include ms-xl2;
        }

        .TwoThirds-3 {
            @include ms-Grid-col;
            @include ms-xl3;
        }

        .TwoThirds-4 {
            @include ms-Grid-col;
            @include ms-xl4;
        }

        .TwoThirds-5 {
            @include ms-Grid-col;
            @include ms-xl5;
        }

        .TwoThirds-6 {
            @include ms-Grid-col;
            @include ms-xl6;
        }

        .TwoThirds-7 {
            @include ms-Grid-col;
            @include ms-xl7;
        }

        .TwoThirds-8 {
            @include ms-Grid-col;
            @include ms-xl8;
        }

        .TwoThirds-9 {
            @include ms-Grid-col;
            @include ms-xl9;
        }

        .TwoThirds-10 {
            @include ms-Grid-col;
            @include ms-xl10;
        }

        .TwoThirds-11 {
            @include ms-Grid-col;
            @include ms-xl11;
        }

        .TwoThirds-12 {
            @include ms-Grid-col;
            @include ms-xl12;
        }
    }
}
```

after that you may use the fallowing classes to specify what UI you would like to have when the webpart is rendered in different section: OneColumnSection-x, TwoColumnsSection-x, ThreeColumnsSection-x, OneThird-x, TwoThirds-x

here is the link to the article I used in my solution (still works :)... but please be aware that the modern page UI (class names, tags.. etc) may change in the future so this solution/workaround may fail if MS decides to change some naming)
https://ypcode.wordpress.com/2019/01/10/spfx-webparts-responsive-to-modern-page-sections/

Comment: This looks interesting

Answer (score 0):

spfx should support grid system from fabric UI.

If you are using only `ms-sm3` to the blocks, then changing the column layout from one column to two columns may not be able to trigger the adjustment.

You can add some extra conditions to the blocks, e.g. `ms-sm2 ms-md4 ms-lg3`, such that there will be 6 blocks in a row in a small size screen; 3 blocks in a row in a middle size screen and 4 blocks in a row in a large size screen.

Comment: Your solutions is true when you look in different devices but, when you see same screen with multiple layouts in desktop it will fail. Above screenshots are from 15 inch laptop device

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you set a "[min-width](https://github.com/kongmengfei/SharedSPFx/blob/master/nojsframewp/src/webparts/nojsframewp/NojsframewpWebPart.module.scss)" on the block to prevent excessive shrink.

[image]

Or you can use [flex box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) layout:

- codepen.io/team/css-tricks/pen/EKEYob?editors=1100

[image]
[image]

BR